# mysql_ping - is there overuse of it?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a client app that constantly pings server with `mysql_ping()`. This is happening in intervals of every 1-5 seconds, how costly would this be if plenty of users use the app?

The reason i am doing it is to avoid MySQL reconnection-delay and unless there is something going on between client and server every 1-5-10 seconds(not sure) then reconnection is required and it doesn’t help me at all.

edit: This is **not web-app** but local software so by client app(machine) i am talking about application users who need to constantly ping server

Comment: Is the client and server the same machine?

Comment: no, the client machines are application users who need to ping server constantly

Comment: What's an "application user"?

Comment: i edited topic some more to avoid confusion...

Comment: I would first consider increasing the timeout and then maybe introducing a caching layer to reduce calls to the database and only then try putting a ping in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the clients are different physical machines, then ping *may* (and I stress the may) be a good idea.

By avoiding the reconnection you certainly speed things up.

The main drawback is the number of users - MySQL has a limit to users, and if each one of them is always connected you may hit that limit.

If you don't hit the limit I see no harm in it.

As far as network usage a ping is quite minimal. Certainly if this is a local LAN (not over the internet) there is no harm there.